# keyboard shortcuts not working after upgrading to 17.04

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I had Ubuntu 16.10 with Cinnamon installed and I upgraded to 17.04. All of my shortcuts and keyboard settings are not working,although they are still defined. I looked at some previous answers to this type of problem. I tried adding a desktop entry to run the gnome-daemon but it did not work. I see that others are also experiencing similar problems after upgrading to 17.04.

How can I get my keyboard back?

Thanks
Eitan